# Configure Compass within a CakePHP project

Tags: cakephp, sass, compass-sass

I've been looking into Compass and the more I look, the more it feels like the way that CSS should be written. As a test case, I'd like to use it in one of my CakePHP projects. Unfortunately, I'm having some trouble with the initial configuration. Specifically, with getting the resources in the right place and referenced properly in the compiled CSS.

I'm creating a `:stand_alone` project in my `/app` directory. Well, that's what I *want* to do. Compass doesn't seem to like that. In creating the project, I've told it where to put the css, images and js and those resources do, in fact, make it to the proper directory. Unfortunately, because I'm not creating the directory in the webroot, the resources are being referenced incorrectly when compiled.

I'm creating the Compass project in my CakePHP `app/` directory with this command:

```
$ compass -f blueprint --sass-dir sass --css-dir webroot/css/ --images-dir webroot/img/ --javascripts-dir webroot/js/ --output-style compact .
```

The compiled CSS, though, wants to reference Blueprint's `showgrid.png` image as:

```
url('/webroot/img/grid.png?1264969358')
```

I suppose this is a pretty predictable result, but I can't figure out how to get the compiled CSS to reference the correct `/img/grid.png?whatever` path. Is that even possible? Am I forced to create my Compass project directly in my webroot?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Content of my `config.rb` file:

```
# Require any additional compass plugins here.
project_type = :stand_alone
# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "webroot/css"
sass_dir = "sass"
images_dir = "webroot/img"
http_images_path = "/img"
javascripts_dir = "webroot/js"
output_style = :compact
```

Comment: For all who want to know: http://compass-style.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running Compass v0.10 and using the following configuration:

```
# Require any additional compass plugins here.
# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
http_path = "/"
sass_dir = "sass"
css_dir = "webroot/css"
images_dir = "webroot/images"
javascripts_dir = "webroot/js"
http_stylesheets_dir = "css"
http_javascripts_dir = 'js'
http_images_dir = 'images'
# To enable relative paths to assets via compass helper functions. Uncomment:
# relative_assets = true
```

provides the expected results.

Compass v0.10 is just about to be release, you can install it with:

```
(sudo) gem install compass --pre
```

To create a project using this config:

1. Create a project directory
2. Save the config into `config.rb` in the project directory.
3. From within your project directory run the command: `compass install blueprint`

Comment: Thanks, Chris. Am I inferring correctly, then, that this is a known issue in versions prior to 0.10? I'm running 0.8.17. I'll upgrade tonight and see whether that helps. With my current version, I've tried the `http_*` paths with and without the initial "/", but nothing has worked for me.

Comment: I'm encountering the same problem on 0.11.5

Comment: ...oh, "gem install compass --pre" did the trick again, is it supposed to work in pre editions only? :)

Answer (score 1):

Rails and other frameworks have the sass files and configuration in the project root, outside the public webroot. A stand-alone project should work fine this way too.

Are you using `image_url()` for when you're referencing an image?

In your `compass.config` file you can set the `http_images_path` if it's different from your directory path. See the [configuration page](http://wiki.github.com/chriseppstein/compass/configuration-reference) in the wiki for more details.

Comment: I've actually tried that, but maybe I'm entering an incorrect value. What I've been trying to enter is `/img`. I've pasted the content of my config.rb file above.

Comment: Although the image I was originally speaking of was the grid.png image (which I'm not referencing manually at all), I did try `image_url()` on one of my own images with no luck. `image_url("logo.png")` compiles as `url(/webroot/img/logo.png)`.

Comment: did you restart your compass --watch process after changing the config?

Comment: No, but in a separate terminal window, I ran `compass -u`. It reported that no changes were made. When I get home, I'll ensure that I restart the watch process.